# "error: changes meaning" when installing Apache qpid

Tags: c++, installation, qpid

I'm trying to install the qpid proton 0.14.0 libraries on a SUSE linux system in order to integrate AMQP messaging into a large c++ program. The installation requires calling "cmake" and "make all". Upon calling "make all", the build gets to 32% complete, then throws errors:

```
Scanning dependencies of target qpid-proton-cpp
[ 32%] Building CXX object proton-c/bindings/cpp/CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-cpp.dir/src/connection.cpp.o
In file included from {Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/./././link.hpp:31,
                 from {Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/././receiver.hpp:27,
                 from {Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/./session.hpp:27,
                 from {Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/connection.hpp:28,
                 from {Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/src/connection.cpp:24:
{Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/././././sender_options.hpp:87: error: declaration of ‘proton::sender_options& proton::sender_options::delivery_mode(proton::delivery_mode)’
{Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/./././././delivery_mode.hpp:30: error: changes meaning of ‘delivery_mode’ from ‘struct proton::delivery_mode’
In file included from {Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/./././link.hpp:32,
                 from {Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/././receiver.hpp:27,
                 from {Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/./session.hpp:27,
                 from {Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/connection.hpp:28,
                 from {Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/src/connection.cpp:24:
{Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/././././receiver_options.hpp:83: error: declaration of ‘proton::receiver_options& proton::receiver_options::delivery_mode(proton::delivery_mode)’
{Install_dir}/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/./././././delivery_mode.hpp:30: error: changes meaning of ‘delivery_mode’ from ‘struct proton::delivery_mode’
make[2]: *** [proton-c/bindings/cpp/CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-cpp.dir/src/connection.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [proton-c/bindings/cpp/CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Researching the "changes meaning of 'delivery_mode' from 'struct proton::delivery_mode' error leads me to belive that this is an issue to do with a constructor function having the same name as a struct. I'm including the deliver_mode structure declaration below. Any thoughts as to how I can get these libraries to install? Thanks!

```
namespace proton {

/// The message delivery policy to establish when opening a link.
/// This structure imitates the newer C++11 "enum class" so that
/// The enumeration constants are in the delivery_mode namespace.
struct delivery_mode {
    /// Delivery modes
    enum modes {
        /// No set policy.  The application must settle messages
        /// itself according to its own policy.
        NONE = 0,
        /// Outgoing messages are settled immediately by the link.
        /// There are no duplicates.
        AT_MOST_ONCE,
        /// The receiver settles the delivery first with an
        /// accept/reject/release disposition.  The sender waits to
        /// settle until after the disposition notification is
        /// received.
        AT_LEAST_ONCE
    };

    /// @cond INTERNAL

    delivery_mode() : modes_(NONE) {}
    delivery_mode(modes m) : modes_(m) {}
    operator modes() { return modes_; }

    /// @endcond

  private:
    modes modes_;
};

}
```

Comment: Don't see proton::receiver_options or proton::sender_options, where are they?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the GCC version. Some versions of GCC treat this situation as an error, and you must be using one of those versions. One solution is to resolve the ambiguity by specifically referencing the type `proton::delivery_mode`. I also had an issue with building the interop tests, which I fixed. I still can't build the Python bindings that I want, but Proton itself builds with the changes below. I'll update this answer if I figure out the Python bindings issue.

```
diff --git a/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/receiver_options.hpp b/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/receiver_options.hpp
index 413e4d4..111865d 100644
--- a/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/receiver_options.hpp
+++ b/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/receiver_options.hpp
@@ -70,7 +70,7 @@ class receiver_options {
     PN_CPP_EXTERN receiver_options& handler(class messaging_handler&);

     /// Set the delivery mode on the receiver.
-    PN_CPP_EXTERN receiver_options& delivery_mode(delivery_mode);
+    PN_CPP_EXTERN receiver_options& delivery_mode(proton::delivery_mode);

     /// Automatically accept inbound messages that aren't otherwise
     /// released, rejected, or modified (default is true).
diff --git a/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/sender_options.hpp b/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/sender_options.hpp
index 9d7bb42..58a42cb 100644
--- a/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/sender_options.hpp
+++ b/proton-c/bindings/cpp/include/proton/sender_options.hpp
@@ -74,7 +74,7 @@ class sender_options {
     PN_CPP_EXTERN sender_options& handler(class messaging_handler&);

     /// Set the delivery mode on the sender.
-    PN_CPP_EXTERN sender_options& delivery_mode(delivery_mode);
+    PN_CPP_EXTERN sender_options& delivery_mode(proton::delivery_mode);

     /// Automatically settle messages (default is true).
     PN_CPP_EXTERN sender_options& auto_settle(bool);
diff --git a/proton-c/bindings/cpp/src/interop_test.cpp b/proton-c/bindings/cpp/src/interop_test.cpp
index de6ae63..a383b26 100644
--- a/proton-c/bindings/cpp/src/interop_test.cpp
+++ b/proton-c/bindings/cpp/src/interop_test.cpp
@@ -33,6 +33,7 @@ namespace {
 using namespace std;
 using namespace proton;

+using proton::codec::get;
 using proton::codec::encoder;
 using proton::codec::decoder;
```